# Jenkins Kubernetes plugin: How to build image from Dockerfile and run steps inside the image

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the Jenkins [kubernetes-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin). Is it possible to build a docker image from a Dockerfile and then run steps inside the created image? The plugin requires to specify an image in the pod template so my first try was to use docker-in-docker but the step `docker.image('jenkins/jnlp-slave').inside() {..}` fails:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      //cloud 'kubernetes'
      label 'mypod'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:1.11
    command: ['cat']
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build Docker image') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave.git'
        container('docker') {
          sh "docker build -t jenkins/jnlp-slave ."
          docker.image('jenkins/jnlp-slave').inside() {
            sh "whoami"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fails with:

```
WorkflowScript: 31: Expected a symbol @ line 31, column 11.
             docker.image('jenkins/jnlp-slave').inside() {
```

Comment: Why/how does it fail?

Comment: It fails with `Expected a symbol @`, see above.

Comment: Ok so there are likely going to be multiple issues to address here. The first is you really should be building your image with `image = docker.build('jenkins/jnlp-slave')` and then running inside via `image.inside()`. There may be a couple more Jenkins issues and Docker issues after that, but that is a good start.

Comment: Awesome this works! Thank you very much!! I will post the fully working example as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Matt in the comments this works:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      //cloud 'kubernetes'
      label 'mypod'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:1.11
    command: ['cat']
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build Docker image') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave.git'
        container('docker') {
          script {
            def image = docker.build('jenkins/jnlp-slave')
            image.inside() {
              sh "whoami"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that `docker.build('jenkins/jnlp-slave')` here will always be done from scratch. In order to get docker caching in my team, we share a cache on s3, rebuild the image in a first stage, then push to artifactory, then load the build image container... This is quite complex and very manual. Any simple solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 container('docker') {
        script {
        def image = docker.build("cusdock","CustomImage")
        image.inside(){
          sh "docker info"
        }
    }
 }
```

Here CustomImage is the directory inside your git repo which contains Dockerfile which will build your custom image.
That image will be build and tagged as cusdock
docker info will be run inside your custom docker image.